# Getting all statics properties of a sencha class

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Got a Sencha Touch 2 class defined as follow:

```
Ext.define("Foo.Bar", {

    statics: {

        lol: "trololol",

        /* ... many others ... */

        asd: "trololol"

    }

});
```

If I `console.log('%o', Foo.Bar);` I get the following output:

```
function () {
    return this.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

How can I get a readable representation of all the statics in my class without checking for all properties?

[EDIT] After defining my class I am manipulating the statics, adding some properties or modifying their contents, so I need a solution that works at a given time in the application execution, giving me all the statics properties of the class and their values.

Comment: The statics get added to the class at definition time, so it doesn't track them after. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you interested in individual properties? `console.log(Foo.Bar.lol)` should do

Comment: @Evan I am manipulating those properties and want to know their status at a given time in the application's lifetime.

Comment: @Pranav, no I need a way to show all the statics at once since there are plenty of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the existing property names like this:

```
console.log(Ext.Object.getKeys(Foo.Bar));
```

You can then refine this concept to get a more readable and/or useful output. For example:

```
function getStatics(cls, includeFunctions, includeProto) {
    var isFunction = Ext.isFunction,
        o = {},
        v;
    Ext.each(Ext.Object.getKeys(Foo.Bar), function(key) {
        if (includeProto || cls.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            v = cls[key];
            if (includeFunctions || !isFunction(v)) {
                o[key] = v;
            }
        }
    });
    return o;
}

console.log(getStatics(Foo.Bar));
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your helper succesfully for what I had to do, even if it includes some statics other than that I defined (Sencha's stuff: $className, $isClass etc...) guess I could filter those out easily by name. I wait some more before accepting to see if better answers come up.

Answer (score 0):

This may not do exactly what you want, but why not make use of individual static properties being accessible:

```
Ext.define("Foo.Bar", {
    statics: {
        statics : {
            lol: "trololol",
            /* ... many others ... */
            asd: "trololol"
        }
    }
});
```

now you can access your properties using `Foo.Bar.statics`

Comment: This could be a nice workaround but I would like to keep my code clean (no unnecessary nesting), plus I don't wont to search / replace a very big project just to get a debug message.